# Scala [2.11.6] -- is there an elegant way to create cache-keys for objects based on an Int/Long and the full class name?

Tags: scala, caching

I want to use a cache to hold recently accessed objects that just came from a database read.

The database primary key, in my case, will be a Long.

In each case I'll have an Object (Case Class) that represents this data.

The combination of the Long plus the full class name will be a unique identifier for finding any specific object. (The namespace should never have an conflicts as class names do not use numbers (as a rule?). In any case for this usage case I control the entire name space so not a huge concern).

The objects will be relatively short lived in the cache - I just see a few situations where I can save memory by holding the same immutable Object more than once as opposed to different instances of the same Object that would be extremely difficult to "pass everything everywhere" to avoid.

This also would help performance in situations where different eyeballs are checking out the same stuff but this is not the driver for this particular use case (just gravy).

My concern is now for **every** **time** I need a given object I'll need to recreate the cache key. This will involve a Long.toString and a String Concat. The case classes in question have a val in their companion object so that they know their class name without any further reflection occurring.

I'm thinking of putting a "cache" together in the companion object for the main cache keys as I wish to avoid the (needless?) repeat ops per lookup as well as the resultant garbage collection etc. (The fastest code to run is the code that never gets written (or called) - right?)

Is there a more elegant way to handle this? Has someone else already solved this specific problem?

I thought of writing a key class but even with a val (lazy or otherwise) for the hash and toString I still get a hit for each and every object I ask for as now I have to create the key object each time. (That could of course go back into the companion object key cache but if I go to the trouble of setting up that companion object cache for keys the key object approach is redundant.)

As a secondary ask of this question - assuming I use a Long and a full class name (as a String) which is most likely to get the quickest pull for the cache?

```
Long.toString + fullClassName
```

or

```
fullClassName + Long.toString
```

The Long IS a string in the key so assuming it is a string "find" on the cache which would be easier to index find? The numeric portion first or the string class name.

Numbers first means you wade through ALL the objects with matching numbers searching for the matching class whereas class first means you find the block of a particular class first but you have to go to the very end of the string to find the exact match.

I suspect the former might be more easily optimized for a "fast find" (I know in MySQL terms it would be...)

Then again perhaps someone already has a dual-key lookup based cache? :)

Comment: how many instances of the application will exist? if there are more than one, are you assuming a distributed cache or each app instance has its own cache?

Comment: Good question - was not trying to assume anything but I would suspect each app to have it's own cache. It's just short lived to handle deeply nested hierarchical objects that tend to chase their own tails from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import play.api.cache.Cache
```

It turns out that `Cache.getOrElse[T](idAsString, seconds)` actually does most of the heavy lifting!

[T] is of course a `type` in Scala and that is enough to keep things separated in the cache. Each [T] is a unique, separate and distinct bucket in the cache.

So `Cache.getOrElse[AUser](10, 5)` will get a completely different object from `Cache.getOrElse[ALog](10, 5)` (where the ID of 10 just happens to be the same for the purpose of illustration here).

I'm currently doing this with thousands of objects across hundreds of types so I know it works...

I say most of the work as the Long has to be `.toString`'ed before it can be used as a key. Not a complete GC disaster as I simply set up a Map to hold the most commonly/recently `.toString`'ed Long values.

For those of you that simply don't get the value of this consider a simple log screen which is very common in most web applications.

```
2015/10/22 10:22 - Johnny Rotten - deleted an important file
2015/10/22 10:22 - Johnny Rotten - deleted another important file
2015/10/22 10:22 - Johnny Rotten - looked up another user
2015/10/22 10:22 - Johnny Rotten - added a bogus file
2015/10/22 10:22 - Johnny Rotten - insulted his boss
```

Under Java (Tomcat) there would typically a **single** Object that represented that user (Johnny Rotten) and that **single** Object would be linked to each and every time the Name of that user appeared in the log display.

Now under Scala we tend to create a new instance (Case Class) for each and every line of the log entry simply because we have no (efficient/plumbing) way of getting to the last used **instance** of that Case Class. The Log itself tends to be a case class and it has a `lazy val` of the User Case Class.

So, along comes user-x and they look up a log and the set the pagination to 500 lines and low and behold we now have 500 case classes being created simply to display a users name (the "who" in each log entry).

*And then a few seconds later we have yet another 500 `User` Case Classes when they hit refresh because they didn't think they clicked the mouse right the first time...*

With a simple cache however that holds a recently accessed object for all of say 5 seconds, all we create for the entire 500 log entries is a single instance of a `User` Case Class for each unique name we display in the log.

In Scala Case Classes are immutable so the single instance is perfectly acceptable use case here and the GC has no needless work to do...

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it extremely simple until you had concrete performance metrics to the contrary. Something like:

```
trait Key {

  def id: Long

  lazy val key: String = s"${getClass.getName}-${id}"

}

case class MyRecordObject(id: Long, ...) extends Key
```

Use a simple existing caching solution like [Guava Caching](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained).

To your secondary question, I would not worry about the performance of generating a key at all until you could actually prove key generation is a bottleneck (which I kind of doubt it ever would be).

Comment: Not worried about the cost of key generation - I'm worried about the cost of garbage collection afterwards and/or the cost of memory as tens of thousands of these keys float around until GC.

Comment: @Techmag, you are probably better off addressing GC concerns through JVM tuning.

Comment: If I knew the answer I wouldn't be asking the question :) Why try to fix something if you can avoid creating a mess in the first place?

Comment: If you consider creating many short-lived objects as a mess, then I don't know that Scala (or the JVM in general) is the right choice.

Comment: They say the best code to writer is the code that never gets run. In other words efficiency is always the mantra. I'm not against many short-lived objects at all -- I just work with pages that have historically had datasets in the tens of thousands of objects (detailed systems overviews). All I'm trying to do is avoid the *needless* creation of many short lived objects. Every project *balances* one set of criteria against another and in this case I want to conserve memory and spare the CG some effort due to complexity of this project's dataset coupled with the required displays.

Comment: FYI: I have no plans on building a cache - it is only the KEYS (or key management) that I am focused on. There are excellent caches already so no need to reinvent that wheel. I guess ring-buffer might be a better term for where i want to store my most recently used keys in the companion object. It would cost me only a Long (as the "key" and the main cache key key as the "value"

Comment: I would say your efficiency mantra is superseded by the old Knuth quote of "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil". Unless you have some undisclosed performance characteristic (ie, embedded system with real RAM constraints, real-time computing constraint a la twitter or a financial system, etc) these keys are not going to be your primary bottleneck. Until you have concrete performance data about an abundance of short-lived keys being the primary performance issue, your time is going to be far better spent elsewhere.

Comment: I agree with you 100% Brian -- I still however do try to design and build efficiently in the first place. One side effect of Scala + Play together appears to be that we tend to use Java -- which used to have a very persistent memory model -- much like PHP is used on other sites. There tends to be a whack of new temporary objects per page (and page refresh) . As I already have programs that alert me to memory crunch in the tomcat/jvm world then I can only imagine what this new model will do to memory. I'm merely trying to solve the problem in design before I have to solve it in production.